# pip install not working / responding - stuck until cancelled

Tags: python, pip

When I try using `pip install` it freezes until I cancel the operation. I get the same with `pip list`.

[image]

I'm running on WSL Ubuntu 20.04 but I have no DNS issues. Tried with Google DNS, and WSL default, but didn't work.

Adding verbose `-vvv` does nothing different. Trying to upgrade `pip` gives the same behavior.

```
$ pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)

$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.10
```

Traceback:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==20.0.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 96, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._internal.network.session import PipSession
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip._internal.network.auth import MultiDomainBasicAuth
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/auth.py", line 36, in <module>
    import keyring  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .core import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/core.py", line 189, in <module>
    init_backend()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/core.py", line 93, in init_backend
    keyrings = filter(limit, backend.get_all_keyring())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/util/__init__.py", line 21, in wrapper
    func.always_returns = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/backend.py", line 210, in get_all_keyring
    return list(rings)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/util/__init__.py", line 31, in suppress_exceptions
    for callable in callables:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/util/properties.py", line 26, in __get__
    return self.fget.__get__(None, owner)()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/backend.py", line 67, in viable
    cls.priority
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/util/properties.py", line 26, in __get__
    return self.fget.__get__(None, owner)()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/backends/kwallet.py", line 37, in priority
    bus = dbus.SessionBus(mainloop=DBusGMainLoop())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/_dbus.py", line 212, in __new__
    return Bus.__new__(cls, Bus.TYPE_SESSION, private=private,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/_dbus.py", line 102, in __new__
    bus = BusConnection.__new__(subclass, bus_type, mainloop=mainloop)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 124, in __new__
    bus = cls._new_for_bus(address_or_type, mainloop=mainloop)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/exceptions.py", line 47, in __init__
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Can you share the traceback you get when you interrupt the process? It should show you where it's getting stuck

Comment: @IainShelvington added traceback

Comment: btw it is working when inside venv

Comment: Looks like a known issue https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7883

Comment: Possible work around is to disable the keyring? `PYTHON_KEYRING_BACKEND=keyring.backends.null.Keyring
pip install -h`

Comment: @IainShelvington that didn't work

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me, as I had done some X11 setup recently:

```sh
unset DISPLAY
```

I have no idea how that could be related but it did the trick.

Source: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7883#issuecomment-852102601